# Property or indexer cannot be assigned to - it is read only

Tags: c#

Hey i just started by C# class 2 weeks ago so i am beginner programmer 
and i am having trouble with my code. i have 2 classes, one of them is the test case that runs the program and the other has private variables. my variables color, NumOfWheels, StartingPoint, CurrentSpeed, and Mileage says property or indexer cannot be assigned to - it is read only when i try to build it. how do i fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Homework1 
{
    class Car
    {
        private string color;
        private int numOfWheels;
        private int startingPoint;
        private int mileage;
        private int currentSpeed;

        public Car()
        {
            Color = "";
            NumOfWheels = 4;
            StartingPoint = 100000;
            CurrentSpeed = 0;
            Mileage = 0;
        }

        public Car(string color, int numOfWheels, int startingPoint, int currentSpeed, int mileage)
        {
            Color = color;
            NumOfWheels = numOfWheels;
            StartingPoint = startingPoint;
            CurrentSpeed = currentSpeed;
            Mileage = mileage;
        }

        public virtual void setcolor(string color)
        {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public virtual void setnumOfWheels(int numOfWheels)
        {
            this.numOfWheels = numOfWheels;
        }


        public virtual string Color
        {
            get
            {
                return color;
            }
        }

        public virtual double NumOfWheels
        {
            get
            {
                return numOfWheels;
            }
        }

        public virtual int StartingPoint
        {
            get
            {
                return startingPoint;
            }
        }

        public virtual int CurrentSpeed
        {
            get
            {
                return currentSpeed;
            }
        }

        public virtual int Mileage
        {
            get
            {
                return mileage;
            }
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return (" color " + color + " numOfWheels" + numOfWheels + "startingPoint " + startingPoint + "mileage" + mileage + "current speed" + currentSpeed);
        }
     }
}

********************************************************************************
///  this is the test case that runs the program 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class CarTest
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Car myCar = new Car();


                Console.WriteLine("*****************************"); 
                Console.WriteLine("*                           *"); 
                Console.WriteLine("* WELCOME TO CAR MANAGER    *");
                Console.WriteLine("*  By <<my Name>>   *"); 
                Console.WriteLine("*                           *");
                Console.WriteLine("*****************************");



            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the number of wheels of a car");
            int numOfWheels = Console.Read();
                myCar.setWheels(numOfWheels);



            Console.WriteLine("Enter the color of the car");
            String color = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Current mileage will be set to zero");

            Console.WriteLine("The current starting point will be set to 100000");

            Console.Write("The current status of your car \n{0:D} Wheels, \n{1}, \n{2:D} Miles and \nCAR POINT = {3:D}", myCar.getNumOfWheels, 
            myCar.getColor, myCar.getMileage, myCar.getStartingPoint);

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the owner's name");
            String name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the miles the car ran in this week");
            int milesThisWeek = Console.ReadLine;
            myCar.setMileage(Mileage);

            Console.WriteLine("This car is owned by n{1}", name); 


                Console.WriteLine("===>The current status of your car:");
            Console.WriteLine("Wheels: " + myCar.getWheels());
            Console.WriteLine("Color: " + myCar.getColor());
                Console.WriteLine("Current Mileage: " + myCar.getMileage());
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Point: " + myCar.getStartingPoint());
            Console.WriteLine("************ Thank you for using CAR MANAGER *************");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close console…….");    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to set a property:

```
Color = "";
```

(among other places)  But that property doesn't have a setter, only a getter:

```
public virtual string Color
{
    get
    {
        return color;
    }
}
```

In order to set the value of a property, it needs a setter:

```
public virtual string Color
{
    get
    {
        return color;
    }
    set
    {
        color = value;
    }
}
```

(repeat for your other properties as well)

---

It *looks like* you're trying to create Java-like setter methods:

```
public virtual void setcolor(string color)
{
    this.color = color;
}
```

This *works*, and you can call those instead of trying to set the properties:

```
setColor("");
```

*But* it's not the expected convention in C#.  The properties can manage the backing variables themselves.  In fact, you can remove the backing variables entirely and use auto-implemented properties for simple values:

```
public virtual string Color { get; set; }
```

If you just need to hold a value, a simple property does that just fine.  Methods are more for operations in code, not for getting/setting simple values.  (Additionally, you wouldn't want to get into the habit of calling a lot of methods from a constructor.  A constructor should really just build the state of the object and nothing else.)

Comment: And remove all those 'java-like' setX,setY methods.